# Java Scanner gets integer input second time

Tags: java

I should check if the input value equals 'end' or a number..

I tried this but it reads integer value only second time I enter.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (play){
       int answer = ask();

        if (scan.next().equals("end")){
            System.out.println("ended");
            play = false;
        } else if (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            int number = scan.nextInt();
            if (number == answer){...
```

Comment: `next()` already reads the first number. Then you compare it with  `"end"`, and if it does not match, you throw it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because **scan.next()** is taking the value to check if it's equals to "end", so the second condition *fails to get evaluated because there's no next value* (until there is).
You can fix the problem by swapping the conditions:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (play){
       int answer = ask();

        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int number = scan.nextInt();
            if (number == answer) System.out.println("correct");
        } else if (scan.next().equals("end")){
            System.out.println("ended");
            play = false;
        } 
    }
```

Furthermore you can avoid declaring some variables which are used just to check a condition, as well as take advantage of if condition left to right evaluation:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true){
   int answer = 5;
   
    if (!scan.hasNextInt() && scan.next().equals("end")){
        /*This works because if the next value is an int,
        scan.next() is not called at all*/
        System.out.println("ended");
        break;
    }
    
    if (scan.hasNextInt() && scan.nextInt() == answer){
        /*Same logic as the other if, when the value is not an int,
        scan.nextInt() is not called, so that other values do not
        lead to a crash*/
        System.out.println("correct");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "the second condition fails because there's no next value (until there is)." - it doesn't fail, it doesn't get evaluated until there is a second value to read.

Comment: @Sören I should have phrased that better, I meant exactly what you said in the second comment. On the other hand this does fix the problem because if the next value is an int it gets evaluated before checking if it's equals to "end". So inputting the correct number first prints "correct";

Comment: posted code is not responsible for opening `System.in` - usually this code should not close it either - calling `scan.close()` should not be called since it will also close `System.in` - better would be to have included a message if the input does not match anything

Comment: @user85421 You are right, I assumed it was also the end of the program, but that might not be the case.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `hasNextInt`, so I'll delete my first comment.

Comment: end of the program -> it would be closed anyway -- (only) resources the code is opening  should be closed by that code (unless documented differently) ((in this specific case, it is a bit *unfortunate* that `Scanner#close` also closes the its source))

Comment: @user85421 I see. My OOP professor told us it's good practice to close it, even if it's System.In, but I can't really recall why. On the other hand thanks for your responses!